# Node.js error crawling with npm crawler

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, web-crawler

When using the npm crawler to crawl links, I get the error:

```
C:\Users\ryani\Desktop\JavaScript\crawler\crawler.js:15
                                $('a').each(function(index, value) {
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

I've tried setting timeouts and various debugging techniques... I'm not sure why it is getting undefined; when I put the code in a  tag on an html page, it works fine.

crawler.js:

```
var Crawler = require("crawler");

var c = new Crawler({
    "maxConnections":10,

    "callback":function(error, res, $) {

        if (error) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            $('a').each(function(index, value) {
                console.log($(this).attr('href'));
                //c.queue(href)
            });
        }
    }
});

c.queue('http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not initialized Cheerio (var $ = res.$;).

Try this one it fetches all the likes from the provided URL...

```
var Crawler = require("crawler");

var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections: 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page 
    callback: function(error, res, done) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            var $ = res.$;
            var links = [];

            $('a').each(function(i, elem) {
                links[i] = $(this).attr('href');
            });
            // $ is Cheerio by default 
            //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server 
            console.log(links);
        }
        done();
    }
});

c.queue('http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the `Crawler` node module before but looking at their usage example found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler).

The 3 parameters for the callback function are;

1. error - The potential error that might returned by the crawler API
2. res - The response object and `$` is 1 of its property
3. done - another callback function which the code will call when its done processing.

By writing your code as `callback :function(error, res, $) {` the `$` variable is in the 3rd position of parameter so essentially it is been used to represent as the `done` function. Now you're saying `done`.`$` which is incorrect because the function object does not have that property and hence the error.

That is, your code should look something like:

```
    res.$('a').each(function(i, elem) {
        links[i] = $(this).attr('href');
    });
```

Also, you will need to call the `done` parameter otherwise the process will just stuck there. e.g. `$()`. However I recommend you follow their code example as `$` is not a good variable name. Recommend renaming your 3rd variable `$` as `done` instead.

Comment: You're right, I was missing that vital detail.  I was using someone else's code as reference and I shouldn't have been.  Thanks for the answer!